# LinkedIn identity verification failed, says "session invalid or expired"

Tags: authentication, security, linkedin-api, verification

I was trying to login to my LinkedIn account on my laptop (I usually use the mobile app) when I entered my email and password it redirected to a "verify you are a human" page after that came up with an identity verification page where I was asked to enter my phone number.[phone number verification page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcQnn.jpg)

Once I entered my phone number and submitted it gives an error saying "Session invalid or expired".[This is the error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/if0X4.jpg)

As I was trying to login through the web, so I tried through the mobile app as well where it gives the same error. Now I can't login to my account either from the web or mobile app. Anyone with a solution??

Comment: Same issue here too.

Comment: Same problem for me, I think Linkedin blocked my account but I didn't get any notification about this.

Answer (score 0):

Last week, I regained access to my LinkedIn account. Actually, my account was restricted. I believe this error occurred due to an account restriction. They replied to me to a case I submitted where I learned that my account was restricted. I still don't know the reason for my account restriction, but I'll rather share with you what I did to resolve it.

Initially, I thought of this as an authentication failure and attempted to change my password (although I recommend you not change your credentials as this is not an authentication problem). During this process, they asked for an identity verification document, and I provided a photograph of my government-issued ID. Despite submitting that document, I did not receive any reply for days.

Subsequently, I submitted an appeal through their LinkedIn support page (recommended). The link is here. [LinkedIn Help](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/ask/default-social)
In my submission, I detailed the case and attached some screenshots of my issue. After almost 10 days, they replied, stating that my account restriction had been removed.[image: Image is here]

I also attempted to contact them via LinkedIn's Facebook page, but as of now, there has been no reply. If anyone else is experiencing the same issue, try contacting them by submitting a case through the link I shared above.

Answer (score -1):

Very similar thing happened to me! I just created an account, but the e-mail verification messages didn't get through to my e-mail, and then I got logged out, and I haven't got a faintest clue how to get back in again. I've tried the verification with my ID, and to refer to a different e-mail, but that doesn't work either, probably since my first e-mail isn't verified. I only get "Session invalid or expired". Would be nice to be able to send a question on how to solve this without being signed in...

Comment: This does not answer the question posted, please consider commenting instead